# Start Dropbox on Startup

Tags: startup, dropbox

I installed Dropbox (2.0.26) via the command line instructions [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install2).

Dropbox is running great except that it won't start on startup. The command given, `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`,  runs fine via the terminal or <kbd>Al</kbd>t+<kbd>F2</kbd>, but it isn't working in Startup Programs.

I'm probably missing something obvious regarding the syntax for a startup program command. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you have some reason for preferring the CLI route? I installed Dropbox via the GUI route just the other day and have version 2.2.3. Dropbox starts automatically on logging in. I didn't have to do anything.

Comment: The download link at Dropbox links to version 1.6, which was not syncing consistently for me. The CLI route gave me a later version.

Comment: See these two links: 1 --- https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_1.6.0_i386.deb and 2 --- https://www.dropbox.com/download?dl=packages/ubuntu/dropbox_1.6.0_amd64.deb. It says 1.6.0 but the Dropbox version installed is 2.2.3 which I see when I hover on the little Dropbox icon in my panel.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, vasa1. I installed the deb and I got the startup options back in preferences. Oddly, it is still version 2.0.26 for me though.

Comment: Did you do a thorough uninstall of Dropbox first? Including any config files in your home folder? Anyway, I'm pretty new to Dropbox myself!

Comment: I didn't. I kept the config files and just installed the deb directly. No problems. I just tested a restart, and it is working perfectly for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Click on the dropbox icon on the top of your screen, hit "preferences" and tick the button where it says "Start dropbox on system startup" in the "general" tab.

Comment: I felt like an idiot for a moment :) but it seems that the option doesn't exist in preferences. My General tab only has boxes for Desktop notification and LAN sync. I feel like you are right that it was there previously, but it isn't now. My version is 2.0.26 if that helps.

Comment: I've got version 2.0.22, but it seems very odd to remove that button.

Comment: As per the comments with vasa1, the CLI install seems to have been missing this option, but if you install the deb directly, you will get the option back.

Comment: This is not working for me.  When I start it from a command line (as described above) the icon appears on the task bar.  I right click, go to preferences and select "Start dropbox on system startup" and click ok.  I reboot the machine and it's not running.

Comment: This does not work if dropbox installed by the terminal command. Dropbox forgets the setting each time restarting.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 , indeed. For Dropbox to autostart without forgetting the setting, I ran `nautilus-dropbox autostart y`  or `caja-dropbox autostart y`    if you are using a Mate Desktop Environment

Comment: `dropbox autostart n` worked for me (Ubuntu Gnome, Dropbox was installed from terminal)

Comment: Ticking the autostart option in preferences does nothing, it unchecks automatically :( Still, nautilus-dropbox autostart y or caja-dropbox autostart y these worked for me, thank you xcvbn

Answer (score 27):

Follow these steps to make Dropbox start up each time.

1. Click on the Ubuntu "Dash" icon
2. Type `Startup Applications` in the Dash search area
3. Click on the "Startup Applications" ico
4. Click "Add" button
5. For "Name:", type `Dropbox`
6. For "Command:", type `/home/{your-username}/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd`
7. For "Comment:", this can be left blank
8. Click "Add" button
9. Click "Close" button
10. Restart your computer

Comment: This works! This is also the default way to do this. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This also worked in Lubuntu 20.10 with minor adjustments. Selecting the checkbox from the Dropbox preferences doesn't work when the installation has been done in command line, as mentioned in other comments.

Comment: This worked for me, except that when I rebooted the machine remotely and logged in via ssh (something that has become routine during the pandemic...) it doesn't autostart.  This shouldn't be a surprise since I'm not starting a gnome session when I ssh to the machine.

Comment: This simple GUI-oriented recipe works on Ubuntu 20.14LTS. However, I still wonder what an effective command line equivalent is. I had tried the `dropbox autostart y` option and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 8):

First you have to create a `dropbox.desktop` file, with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Dropbox
GenericName=File Synchronizer
Comment=Sync your files across computers and to the web
Exec=dropbox start -i
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
StartupNotify=false
```

Once its created, you need to move it to `~/.config/autostart` folder, reboot, and that's it.

[image]

Remark: if dropbox was installed from the command line, the line "Exec=dropbox start -i" doesn't work, it needs to be replaced by "Exec=/home/username/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd" where /home/username is your home directory.

Comment: This fixes the problem of autostarting dropbox for Kubuntu 15.04!

Comment: This does not work on Debian 8.

Comment: I think you will have a permission problem with such a setup. It is not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, although with permissions 755.

Comment: @Masi Its working OK on 14.04.03.  It's been working since the release of 14.04.  You might have other issues.

Comment: RHarris answer works in my setting.

Answer (score 8):

In the terminal, type

```
dropbox autostart y
```

Comment: This is set by default so it's unlikely to be a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

It ships in the autostart function.

Comment: This might cause the following problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/411809/nautilus-dropbox-depends-dropbox-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed

Comment: This might also run into the following bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-dropbox/+bug/1016559

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the other methods: Only this method as stated by previous user has worked for me:

Run:

```
cd /usr/bin
```

Then rename executable with this command:

```
sudo mv dropbox dropbox1
```

Then create a new file called `dropbox` using command:

```
sudo gedit dropbox
```

Then write this:

```
#!/bin/bash
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Save and exit, change premission:

```
sudo chmod 0755 dropbox
```

then restart the computer.

OR

Create a startup application with name say "Dropbox2" and write this line in it.

```
sh -c  ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Save and exit, then restart the computer.

One of the 2 work properly.

Comment: @sijoune rejected edit, because your suggestion will create a new dropbox file in /usr/bin without execution rights.

Answer (score 1):

To add any program on startup, go to 'Dash Home' and choose 'Startup Applications'. There you can add any program that wish to run on startup.

Comment: I have done that. My problem is that the command described in my question does not seem to run from "Startup Applications" despite running fine in the terminal and via Alt+F2.

Comment: Open 'Startup Applications' click 'Add' and enter 'dropbox' in the 'Command' field and see if it works.

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Create a startup application with name say "`dropBOX`" and write this line in it.

```
sh -c  ~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
```

Save and exit, then restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way (and incidentally, the easiest way) I could get this to work on 14.04 without a buggy install or doing a .desktop file (which I couldn't get to work).  I had to install the .deb using these instructions:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 5044912E

sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install dropbox
```

Then you should get a prompt to install Dropbox from the GUI (if you don't, search in your Applications for it and run by clicking the icon).  Once Dropbox is installed and you're logged in, the preferences should default to autostart, but in case they don't, you can right-click on the Dropbox icon, go to "Preferences", and check "Start Dropbox on System Startup"

Got the instructions from this answer (which seems to have been lost in the annals of the forum for some reason): [Running Dropbox at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501274/running-dropbox-at-startup)

Comment: Needed to also do  sudo apt-get install build-essential before dropbox, otherwise there is a failure...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
dropbox start
```

after you install the nautilus-dropbox you will find dropbox on the startup applications list and check it. :)

Comment: It causes one time start, not autostart.

Comment: after you install the nautilus-dropbox you will find dropbox on the startup applications list and check it. :)

Comment: I tried this solution but it installed an old version of dropbox (1.4) which is not functioning correctly.

Comment: dropbox autostart -y

Answer (score 0):

you need to connect it to your account... If you have no gui, you can do it by running the server (after installation), try

```
dropbox start
dropbox status
```

if it is not running, try running the demon directly, and it will give you a link to enter from another computer to verify password, e.g.:

```
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd
This computer isn't linked to any Dropbox account...
Please visit https://www.dropbox.com/cli_link_nonce?nonce=adfalhwelkjfhlasdk to link this device
```