# How to start Dropbox on startup?

Tags: dropbox

I am having the exact same issue as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/315034/start-dropbox-on-startup) but none of the answers worked for me.

For instance, trying [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/364339/209300) I get this error:

```
a@b:~$ cd /usr/bin
a@b:/usr/bin$ sudo cp dropbox dropbox1
[sudo] password for a: 
cp: cannot stat `dropbox': No such file or directory
a@b:/usr/bin$
```

Is there a way to fix this?

---

Reinstalling and selecting "Start Dropbox on System Startup" worked as in `darent`'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the gnome-session-properties utility running in a terminal:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

And add an entry, simply called dropbox with the command to start it. These are my settings:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this, it was one of the answers, http://askubuntu.com/a/315040/209300. It does not work.

Comment: Then your problem is not starting dropbox... the problem is dropbox is not properly installed. I would download it again from the website and install it from scratch.

Comment: what is the best way to uninstall it?

Comment: Just go here: https://www.dropbox.com/install2 download your version (32 or 64 bit) and when it's downloaded double click in the arxive with deb name. The ubuntu software center will do the rest

Answer (score 0):

**Install Dropbox as follows :**

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-dropbox
```

Then while installing, Check on adding the panel Icon.

Right click on the panal Icon and select Preferences. Check on startup option.

**Or with the present dropbox;**

Open the application **Startup Applications**

Click on `Add` button.

Then in the Name field, Type `Dropbox`

In the Command field type `dropbox start -i`

In Comment field type whatever you want. Doesn't matter if it is empty.

Then click on Add and close application